# How to add MIME Type for the Apache webserver?

Tags: 12.04, video, apache2, mime-type, html5

In ubuntu, i am running simple html page that can run mp4 video, i have configured Apache Server and have run simple test page for hello world, its working fine. In Apache Webserver i have read that we need to add the following code to httpd.conf file or to an .htaccess file in the directory where our video files are.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

So my question is where is this httpd.conf or .htaccess file available, do i manually need to create these files or they are stored somewhere.

The code of my HTML Page is like this :

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Please give me the suggestions.

Ankit

Comment: The httpd.conf is located at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and it's a good idea to make a backup of the original file before you play around with it. As for the `.htaccess` file, please refer to @dobey 's answer

Comment: sit its not located there..

Comment: The default file is `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`, sorry about the earlier path.

Answer (score 13):

I added "webm" to `/etc/mime.types`, which was picked up by Apache as well:

```
video/webm                                     webm
```

Answer (score 3):

The default configuration file for the files being served by your Apache installation is `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`. It's a good idea to backup the original file before you play around with this file.

```
#To make a backup of the original config file:    
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.orig
```

Everytime you edit this file, Apache has to be restarted/reloaded for the changes to take effect - `sudo service apache2 restart` (or) `sudo service apache2 reload`, whereas changes in `.htaccess` do not require Apache to be restarted. As @dobey mentioned, the `.htaccess` file goes in the DocumentRoot of the web site.

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles) on how to enable `.htaccess` files.

Excerpt:

> To make `.htaccess` files work as expected, you need to edit this
>   file:
>
> ```
> /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
> ```
>
> Look for a section that looks like this:
>
> ```
> <Directory /var/www/>
>         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>         AllowOverride None
>         Order allow,deny
>         allow from all
>         # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
>         # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
>         #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> You need to modify the line containing ***AllowOverride None*** to
>   read ***AllowOverride All***. This tells Apache that it's okay to
>   allow `.htaccess` files to over-ride previous directives. You must
>   reload Apache before this change will have an effect:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
> ```
>
> *2009.12.08 note:* in the LAMP download about a week ago with Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic) the default configuration file was `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default` and it included
>   `AllowOverride None` under `<Directory />` in addition to `<Directory
>   /var/www/>`. Also, directories in `/www/var/` containing `.htaccess`
>   files defaulted to not giving the Apache server read access, resulting
>   in the Apache error
>
> ```
> (13)Permission denied: /var/www/webapp/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable.
> ```
>
> To fix, `$ sudo nautilus` then right click on the directory with the
>   `.htacces`s file, select Properties, then select Permissions, and give
>   the user group you log in as at least read permission.
>
> See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride for
>   more info on `AllowOverride`.

Answer (score 2):

The `.htaccess` file would be something you create in the `DocumentRoot` directory of your web site.

Comment: sir iam new to linux..how to create this .htaccess...or that httpd.conf

Comment: How did you create the HTML file?

Comment: http://ubuntuexperiment.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/running-aspnet-applications-in-ubuntu-using-modmono/